# Split QString at - (dash) character, list item access

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I tried to split a QString (a filename) and I want to get parts between two dash signs in the filname.

The Filname is for example "0000000398_05WA-1384864213-218.bmp" .

However,

```
QStringList query;
QString filename;
QDirIterator it(qDirPictures, QDirIterator::NoIteratorFlags);

while (it.hasNext()) {

    it.next();
    filename = it.fileName();

    query = filename.split("-");

    qDebug()<<query;
}
```

gives me a correct output:

("0000000398_05WA", "1384864213", "218.bmp")

But if i want to access the second list item in the same iteration with:

```
qDebug()<<query.at(1);
```

I get an

> "ASSERT failure in QList::at: "index out of range"...

However, if i try with:

```
qDebug()<<query.at(0);
```

I get the correct output:

> "0000000398_05WA"

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Does the assert happen in the same iteration as the one with the correct output?

Comment: Yes, it does. If i access position 0 it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could also use [`section`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#section)

```
QDebug() << filename.section("_",1,1); // will print "1384864213"
```

Comment: As i need both numbers, i decided to go with: ` part = filename.section("-",1,1);
 filename = filename.section("-",2,2);
 parttwo = filename.section(".",0,0);` - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for solving the original mehtod:

If somebody wants to go with QString.split in this case:

adding

```
qDirPictures.setFilter(QDir::Files);
```

before the while loop makes it work well with QString.split with the original code. Turns out that without any filters the first two output lines or directory list items are:

```
"."
```

and

```
".."
```

which leads to the out of bounds error.